# JQuery NavBar code causing scrolling to div issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

**Question Background:**

I have a standard bootstrap NavBar that collpases to a button on mobile devices.

**The Issue:**

When the user clicks on an item in the NavBar dropdown list the page will scroll down to the corrosponding div. I have a piece of JQuery that collpases the dropdown menu when the item has been clicks.

**Without** the JQuery to close the dropdown Nav menu the page scrolls down to the div with no issues. **With** the JQuery the page is scrolling down but stops well *after* the set 10px offset.

**Without the JQuery menu closing code - working:**

Note the small 10px above the panel item, this is what is wanted.

[image]

**With the JQuery closing code - Broken:**

Note that the page now scrolls down past the top of the div.

[image]

**The Code:**

The NavBar:

```
 <div class="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarColour" role="navigation" id="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img src="~/Images/DC.png" class="dc">
                </div>
                <div class="middleNavPadding">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Info">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Mission">Our Mission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Gallery">Projects Gallery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The JQuery Menu closing code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar-nav .scroll-link").click(function (event) {
        $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

The JQuery used to scroll to the Div as set in the NavBar menu:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.scroll-link').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var sectionID = $(this).attr("data-id");

        scrollToID('#' + sectionID, 750);
  });
    function scrollToID(id, speed) {
        var offSet = 10;
        var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
    }
});
```

The HTML Markup of the Panel:

```
<div id="Info">

    //panel HTML

</div>
```

**I believe the issue is that the JQuery is setting the 'top' of the page as the bottom of the dropdown menu which is then causing a false offset. Any help with solving a a solution to this would be much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, just add the `height` of the `#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` to your offset.

```
function scrollToID(id, speed) {
    var offSet = 10 + $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1').height(); // NAVBAR HEIGHT !!!
    var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: targetOffset }, speed);
}
```

This should work.